# Is it counter-intuitive to have the property "id" be part of a composite key to uniquely identify an entity?

Tags: performance, naming-conventions, uuid

Struggling with a bit of naming conventions here.

I have an object which is uniquely identifiable through two properties: the UUID of its parent and an auto-incremented count.

Example:

Parent object has an UUID of 04305eb6-cccb-498c-8fab-95e7d933672d
I add a child object to the parent. Its Id is 1.
I add a second child object to the parent. Its Id is 2.
I delete the child with Id of 1.
I add a third child. Its Id is 3.
I delete the child with Id of 3.
I add a fourth child. Its Id is (3 or 4? Not sure which would make more sense)

My questions:

- Is using the property Id here going to be confusing? Should I name it something like countAutoIncrement instead?
- My algorithm would mean that the countAutoIncrement would be 1 + the largest count for the playlist. Is this an OK algorithm? Or should it just always be 1 + the last generated count?

Comment: Which ID is, for all practical purposes, the one that is going to be used everywhere?  ID and UUID seem like a satisfactory naming convention.  In most database systems, ID's don't get re-used (for reasons which should be readily apparent), which means that if you delete 3, the remaining sequence will be 1,2,4.

Comment: For all practical purposes -- the ID will be the auto incremented value. I'm wary because my parent object's ID will be of type 'GUID' but its child object's ID will be of type 'int'. I'm not sure if mixing ID types like that is bad practice, but I suspect I'm trying to make something perfectly logical in an imperfect world.

Comment: I don't really see a problem with that arrangement, provided it is made clear to everyone that's how it works.  But I certainly would make the name different to provide a visual hint that the *type* is different; i.e. `UUID` on the parent, and `ID` on the child.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for your input, RobertHarvey